# Refactor XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My XAML has got very long and hard to maintain. I was wondering if there is a way to do something like refactoring?

Here is a simple example:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="RefactorXAML.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>New</Button>
            <Button>Open</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can I refactor the `Stackpanel` section and write something like this?

```xaml
<Window x:Class="RefactorXAML.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        // Refactored Markup
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried styles (with control templates) or user controls? Is there a reason you can't use those?

Comment: I'm kinda new to this. Which of these you suggest?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could put those buttons in a user control, to make it like this:

```
<Window …
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace">
    <Grid>
        <my:NewAndOpenButtons />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You could also replace the grid by an items control which already includes those buttons, but that way you would impose too many restrictions on the other content, so I wouldn’t do that.

So for the above, your user control would look something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNamespace.NewAndOpenButtons" …>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>New</Button>
        <Button>Open</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks poke, What is `my` ?

Comment: @Vahid `my` is the reference to the namespace. Like you have `x` on top of your file: `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Vahid The `my:` prefix indicates the XML namespace the component comes from. As your custom components don’t live in Microsoft’s built-in component namespace, you will have to define your own prefix. You can name that whatever you like (e.g. `my`), and if the components are defined in the same assembly, you can use a syntax as shown in my answer to define it.

Comment: @poke Just one more question. Each User Control has its own code-behind here. Then the variables I define in my MainWindow won't be available in `User Control`?

Comment: @Vahid That is correct, each user control is meant to be a completely *separate* control where you don’t have access to its internals (like you don’t have access to a button’s internals). Instead, if you want to allow for communication with the “outside”, you define (dependency) properties which you can assign stuff to on the outside.

Comment: It is a bit complicated I'll post it as a new question.

Comment: @poke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060609/access-objects-in-usercontrol-from-mainwindow-in-wpf

Answer (score 4):

1) **using content control**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Stackpanel" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>New</Button>
            <Button>Open</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Stackpanel}"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

2)**create new usercontrol**

[image]

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Button>New</Button>
    <Button>Open</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">

<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Using a content control without a content is somewhat of an anti-pattern. There is absolutely no reason to use a content control in that example, and using one actually gives the impression that you could add content to it.

Comment: @poke well i used contentcontrol here as there is no contenttemplate property for panel.so we can define template for panel using contencontrol.anyway i appriate your opinin.thank you

Comment: Thanks Heena, I chose the second approach.

Comment: @HeenaPatil That’s because a panel isn’t a control (a panel is a component that defines how controls are rendered). Instead of a content control, you could use any other control here, for example the most basic one: [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx), which has no further semantics (like a *content*) :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not only XAML refactoring but global code refactoring. If your Window XAML is too long then your code behind is too long.

What you should do is to refactor your UI by putting separate functionalities in different CustomControls (UserControls is an option but CustomControls are more flexible). So that your window becomes just an aggregation of a few bricks.

Comment: My code-behinds are usually empty, regardless of what’s in the XAML…

Comment: When an application is well organized yes the code behind is usually light. But When most of the application is just in one XAML file then all event handling happens in just one place and it starts to be messy.

Comment: I also have long xamls with practically no code-behind ... just saying.