# Access objects in UserControl from MainWindow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this simple XAML, how can I change the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` in `UserControl1` from the `MainWindow`?

```
<Window x:Class="RefactorXAML.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:refactorXaml="clr-namespace:RefactorXAML"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <refactorXaml:UserControl1></refactorXaml:UserControl1>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Button>Change Text</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl x:Class="RefactorXAML.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextblock">StackOverflow</TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I hate MVVM :(

Comment: MVVM actually has little to do with this. When you are creating a user control, you are creating an independent component. That component then has some interface which you can consume using different ways. One of that is using data binding, another is using code (e.g. in code-behind). Data binding is incredibly useful even if you’re not using MVVM. (Using data binding does *not* mean you’re doing MVVM. Data binding is a core part that allows MVVM, but data binding has been there before and is widely used without MVVM).

Comment: @poke Thanks poke for the clarification, I know I'm resisting to all these new concepts but finally I'll give up. I remember the time when it was very difficult for me to understand the new concepts of OOP and now I can't do anything without it.

Comment: @Vahid Don’t worry and just take your time. I know it’s really confusing at first, especially since you tend to discover all the things at once giving you a huge wall of new stuff to overcome. But once you passed it, you will see all the benefits of cleaner code, separation of concerns and increase of speed that you’ll wonder why you resisted doing it that way earlier :)

Comment: That is true, I received the same advice when I was resisting to learn OOP, and now I wonder how I was doing all these withou OOP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Controls in WPF are usually meant to be some kind of “black boxes”. You shouldn’t (and usually don’t) care about what’s going on inside. Instead, if you want to allow communication, you define a public interface users of that control can communicate with.

In WPF, this public interface is usually made using [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). You can use normal (CLR) properties for many things as well, but usually you want to allow things like data binding, and then you need dependency properties. Definining dependency properties is a bit more complicated than definining normal properties, as they require some stuff to be done additionally. In Visual Studio, there is the `propdp` snippet though, which helps you adding all that boilerplate code in a few simple steps.

So, for your user control, we have a single string property, which we want to expose to the outside. So in the code-behind for that user control, we define that property as a dependency property:

```
public partial class ExampleUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeText", typeof(string), typeof(ExampleUserControl), new PropertyMetadata("default value"));

    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomeTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // this is the same old stuff
    public ExampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

That’s all we need to do to declare the property and make it available to users of your component. Now we just need to add the functionality. As there isn’t some extra logic involved, but as you just want to delegate the value to some other component’s property (TextBlocks’s `Text` property), we can just use data binding. That’s what will work for most cases:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNamespace.ExampleUserControl" …
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

To make the property accessible for data binding, we set the data context to `self` (i.e. to the component itself) and then we can data bind to its own properties.

When using the component then, we can just set the `SomeText` property of it:

```
<my:ExampleUserControl SomeText="Foo" />
```

And as it’s a dependency property, we can also use data binding to get the value from somewhere else (e.g. a view model when using MVVM):

```
<my:ExampleUserControl SomeText="{Binding SomeTextProperty}" />
```

And if you give your control a name, you can also access it and its `SomeText` property in code-behind if you need to do that:

```
<my:ExampleUserControl x:Name="myControl" SomeText="Foo" />
<Button Click="ChangeText_Click" Content="Change text" />
```

```
private void ChangeText_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myControl.SomeText = "Bar";
}
```

In the end, we have a reusable component that is completely separated from the application it is used in. And the application does not need to know about the implementation of that component, and the component does not need to know about where it’s going to be used.

Comment: It is really difficult for me to understand all these at this point in time. But I know this the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Set the name for your `UserControl`:

```
<refactorXaml:UserControl1 x:Name="MyUserControl1" />
```

And in MainWindow try get the `TextBlock` like this:

```
UserControl1 control = MyUserControl1;
var text = control.FindName("MyTextblock") as TextBlock;

if (text != null)
    text.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Or little much shorter:

```
var text = MyUserControl1.FindName("MyTextblock") as TextBlock;

if (text != null)
    text.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: So the trick is to create an instance of the user control in the code behind first. right?

Comment: @Vahid: No, the instance of UserControl creating in XAML, you just get it in code-behind in `control`. Later, trying to find the control using `FindName()` function.

Comment: That’s not really a good solution… no separation of concerns, and you’re leaking implementation details into the parent.

Comment: @poke: I agree, the OP said that he hates MVVM, so I show the simplest solution.

Comment: I just found out that if I make an instance of the `UserControl1` in `MainWindow` code-behind I can easily change any properties of that. But as @poke said it is against the separation of concerns rule.

Comment: You could still do it (in code-behind) with a cleanly defined component, by exposing properties you can access directly (without having to know its implementation details and use `FindName` to access internal components).

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Yes, it is actually I'm tempted to go this way.

Comment: @Vahid Considering that your [original intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059801/refactor-xaml-in-wpf) behind using user controls was to allow code reuse, you really shouldn’t as you will be repeating that code for every single use of the component. And that’s not even considering its actual downsides.

Comment: @poke Each UC is only used once.

Answer (score 1):

if you hate `MVVM`  you can add a public property. But MVVM will make updating source and target easy in this case you can use a `DependencyProperty`

**`Without MVVM`**

here how it should look  your UC

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
            {
                public UserControl1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
        
                }
                public string TextBlockContent { get; set; }
            }
```

your MainWindow XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:refactorXaml="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <refactorXaml:UserControl1 Name="MyUserControl1"></refactorXaml:UserControl1>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Change Text</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

your MainWindow Class

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyUserControl1.TextBlockContent = "here your text "; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but what is `TextBlockContent`? Is it a new property you defined? I wanted to change the `Text` property?

Comment: This answer is unfortunately missing the connection between the CLR property `TextBlockContent` and the user control’s text block.

Comment: @poke Yeah, I guessed so.